# How can I customize the style of the active nav-link in Laravel Splade?

Tags: laravel

I need to change the default laravel splade active nav link style, Is there any chance to do that?

Comment: Please take a look at "how to ask".. Provide a clear question with relevant code. This is a yes or no question.

Answer (score 0):

**Customization**

You can find every bit of styling in Blade templates, so you never have to customize Vue components. You may publish the Blade templates using the **vendor:publish** Artisan command:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="ProtoneMedia\Splade\ServiceProvider" --tag="views"`

Now the templates are available in the **/resources/views/vendor/splade** folder. Only the styled templates are published. The strictly functional components (those without any markup or styling) will not be published, as there's nothing to customize.

**Laravel Configuration File (config/splade.php)**

You may also publish the configuration file. This allows you to configure settings like the Blade Component prefix, SEO defaults, SSR settings, and more.

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="ProtoneMedia\Splade\ServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default laravel splade active nav link style by editing this file: `resources\views\components\nav-link.blade.php`

style for active nav link:

```css
'inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-indigo-400 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
```

style for inactive link:

```css
'inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out';
```